# Find the $AM$ where $AB=4$ and $AD=5$ are the diameters of a circle

Tags: geometry

> Given $ABDC$ rectangle with sides $AB=4,AD=5$, which are also the diameters of a circle,  find $AM$
>
> [image: Problem Diagram]

Comment: As your question stands, it will likely be downvoted and closed because it does not meet our site's standards. Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 5):

A triangle inscribed In an half circumference must be right. So $BMA=\pi/2=AMD$: we get $M$ lies on $BD$ and in particular $AM$ is the height of $BD$ in the right triangle $ABD$. From this we have: $$AM=\frac {AB\cdot AD}{BD}= \frac {AB\cdot AD}{\sqrt{AB^2+AD^2}}=\frac{20}{\sqrt{41}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Verify that $BMD$ lie on a straight line.  Thales may be helpful. Then compute the area of triangle $ADB$ in two different ways.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\theta=\angle MAB$. Due to half circles, hence right triangles,

$$ \cos\theta=\frac{AM}{AB}, \>\>\>\>\> \sin\theta=\frac{AM}{AD}$$

Then,

$$\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta = 1=\frac{AM^2}{AB^2}+\frac{AM^2}{AD^2}$$

Thus,
$$AM= \frac {AB \cdot AD}{\sqrt{AB^2+AD^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$ \angle BMD=\angle BMA+\angle AMD=90^\circ+90^\circ=180^\circ \rightarrow B,M,D$ are collinear

$\left[\triangle ABD\right]=\dfrac{AM \times BD}{2}=\dfrac{AB \times AD}{2}=\dfrac{4\times5}{2}=10 \\AM=\dfrac{20}{BD}=\dfrac{20}{\sqrt{4^2+5^2}}=\boxed{\dfrac{20}{\sqrt{41}}}$

Answer (score 0):

Equation of circle with dia. AB $S_1\,: \,(X-5/2)^2\,+\,Y^2\,=25/4$
$$ S_1. : X^2\,+\,Y^2\,-5X\,=\,0 $$
Equation of circle with dia. AD $ S_2 : X^2\,+\,Y^2\,-4Y\,=0 $
Therefore Equation of AM as common cord will be 5X -4Y =0. Solve with circle $S_1$ we get point M as (80/41 , 100/41)
Hence AM is $\frac{20}{\sqrt{41}}$

Answer (score 0):

The circle with diameter $AB$ has equation $r = 4 \sin \theta$, and the circle with diameter $AD$ has equation $r = 5 \cos \theta$.

Solving $4 \sin \theta = 5 \cos \theta$, we get $\theta = \tan^{-1} \frac{5}{4}$, and $\theta$ has to be in the range of $[0º, 360º)$. You can find one solution by calculator, and the other by using the fact that $\tan \theta = \tan(\theta + 180º)$.

Then you can use $r = 4 \sin \theta$ to find $r$. This gives you the length of $AM$ directly. $4 \sin \left(\tan^{-1} (5/4) + \pi \right)$ is negative, which leaves the only value $4 \sin \left(\tan^{-1} (5/4) \right) = \frac{20}{\sqrt{41}}$.

Answer (score 0):

If we consider $A$ to be the origin, that is point $(0,0)$ then we can generate the equations of the two circles.

For the circle also passing through $D$, we have a centre of $(2.5,0)$ and a radius of $2.5$

Similarly, for the circle passing through $B$, we have a centre of ($0,2)$ and a radius of $2$.

Therefore the equations of the two circles are

\begin{align}\left(x-\frac52\right)^2+y^2 &= \left(\frac52\right)^2 = \frac{25}4\tag{1}\\
x^2+(y-2)^2&=2^2=4\tag{2}\end{align}

We can then find the intersection of the two circles, given we know one intersection is the origin:

From circle $2$, we know
\begin{align}x^2 &= 4-(y-2)^2\\
&=4-(y^2-4y+4)\\
&= -y^2+4y\end{align}

We can then expand circle $1$ and substitute this in:

\begin{align}\left(x-\frac52\right)^2+y^2 &= \frac {25}4\\
x^2-5x+\frac {25}4+y^2 &= \frac{25}4\\
x^2-5x &= -y^2\\
-y^2+4y-5\left(\sqrt{-y^2+4y}\right)&= -y^2\\
4y-5\left(\sqrt{-y^2+4y}\right) &=0\\
(-5)^2\left(\sqrt{-y^2+4y}\right)^2&=(-4y)^2\\
25(-y^2+4y)&=16y^2\\
-25y^2+100y&=16y^2\\
41y^2-100y&=0\\
\implies y=0 &\text{ or } y=\frac{100}{41}\end{align}

We already knew that $y=0$ was a point of intersection so we look at $y=\frac{100}{41}$. The corresponding $x$ point is

\begin{align}x^2 &= -y^2+4y\\
&=-\frac{100}{41}^2+4\left(\frac{100}{41}\right)\\
&=\frac{6400}{1681}\\
x&=\pm\sqrt{\frac{6400}{1681}}\\
&=\frac{80}{41}\end{align}

Now we know the coordinates for the point $M$, we can calculate the length of the line $AM$:

\begin{align}d&=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}\\
&=\sqrt{\left(\frac{80}{41}-0\right)^2+\left(\frac{100}{41}-0\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{20\sqrt{41}}{41}\\
&\approx{3.12}\end{align}